# Automatic checking of iTunes store

Tags: iphone, itunes, itunes-store

I have got a couple of applications on the app store and I am checking daily all available countries to check out if someone left a review on my application and at what place it is in the top-paid rating.

It became really boring to spend time watching over iTunes. But the information I get is very helpful.

Is there a way to automate the process I am doing? Probably there is an application that will satisfy my needs or a way to write a script? Maybe something using AppleScript (I've never tried it before though).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try https://www.appfigures.com/. Checking for reviews and ranking, however, is limited to the paid version, though you can get an idea of how it works during the first trial days.

Answer (score 3):

Get AppSales-Mobile.  It is open source, you need to download and build it.  Note, if you have past weekly/daily sales reports add them to the apps resources and they will be parsed on initial startup.

From: http://github.com/omz/AppSales-Mobile

App Sales Mobile allows iPhone developers to download and analyze their daily and weekly sales reports from iTunes Connect

Comment: "if you have past weekly/daily sales reports add them to the apps resources and they will be parsed on initial startup." -- How did you manage to do that? Are you sure this is supported by AppSales-Mobile?

Comment: Copy the text files into the Resources directory and add them to the project.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the app [AppCritics](http://appshopper.com/link/appcritics)

Answer (score 1):

You may also use this website to get App store reviews: http://www.moopf.com/appstorereviews/

Answer (score 1):

This might be more of a question for [Super User](https://superuser.com/), given that it's not strictly a programming question, but I'll chip in and say that I use [AppViz](http://www.ideaswarm.com/products/appviz/) on a daily basis.  It can do a one-step import of your iPhone application sales data from iTunes Connect, gather all worldwide reviews, and check your application rankings within the top 200 of your category or overall (or top 1000 if you have an account with Applyzer).

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try licensekey.net/salesgraph. It's free.